# Daily URLFetch quotas and "Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script/sheet that is running up against the dreaded "Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch" error. I've checked the "Quotas for Google Services" [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), but for the life of me, I can't see why I'm going above the stated URL fetch calls limit of 20,000/day.  I'm running a script that plugs 6 instances of an ImportJSON function with different URLs into cells in my spreadsheet, and this script is triggered to run every minute.  So my calculations are 6 calls per minute = 360 calls/hr = 8640 calls/day... so what gives?

I've read that there may also be a daily data limit of 30MB, but again, my calculations put me well under: 7.4KB/minute (total data received from the 6 calls) = 444 KB/hr = 10656 KB/day or 10.6 MB/day.

The objective of the script I'm running is to automatically refresh a trading spreadsheet with the latest ticker and orderbook data for three Bitcoin markets (XBTUSD, XBTEUR, and XBTCAD) from the Kraken exchange.  Below is the function that inserts the importJSON calls into the spreadsheet cells:

```
function importJSONupdate() {
var d = new Date();
var timeStamp = d.toLocaleTimeString();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var XBT_Orderbooks = ss.getSheetByName("XBT Orderbooks");

var XBTUSD_LAST = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD", "/result/XXBTZUSD", "noHeaders", "' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B129').setValue(XBTUSD_LAST);

var XBTUSD_ORDERBOOK = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Depth?pair=XBTUSD&count=30", "/result/XXBTZUSD", "noHeaders,noTruncate","' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B134').setValue(XBTUSD_ORDERBOOK);

var XBTEUR_LAST = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTEUR", "/result/XXBTZEUR", "noHeaders", "' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B130').setValue(XBTEUR_LAST);

var XBTEUR_ORDERBOOK = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Depth?pair=XBTEUR&count=30", "/result/XXBTZEUR", "noHeaders,noTruncate","' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B135').setValue(XBTEUR_ORDERBOOK);

var XBTCAD_LAST = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCAD", "/result/XXBTZCAD", "noHeaders", "' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B131').setValue(XBTCAD_LAST);

var XBTCAD_ORDERBOOK = '=ImportJSON("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Depth?pair=XBTCAD&count=30", "/result/XXBTZCAD", "noHeaders,noTruncate","' + timeStamp + '")';
XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B136').setValue(XBTCAD_ORDERBOOK);

XBT_Orderbooks.getRange('B3').setValue(timeStamp);

}
```

Anything I'm miscalculating or otherwise not understanding here?  The only other thing I can think of is that the spreadsheet also has 2 `GoogleFinance()` calls that fetch the CADUSD and EURUSD exchange rates.  Might this need to be factored in to my usage calculations?  The `GoogleFinance()` function seems to update on its own schedule, so I'm not exactly sure how I might account for this...

Comment: 6 calls per minute is 360 calls per hour.  not 60 per hour.  8,640 for the day though, still way below the limit.  Wonder what your code looks like to see what's causing all the calls.

Comment: haha yes you're right, I just edited the post.  thanks for responding, I'll add some code below.

Comment: Have you checked if you exceed [these](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) other limitations?

Comment: hmmm I think I should be good on the "Current Limitations"... nothing jumps out as being out of line...